# Prevent a specific special character from appearing ANYWHERE within a string with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm doing a VERY VERY simple regex, which is: `/^.*@.*\..*[a-z]$/i`

All I'm trying to do is throw something in there that will fail if there is a `<` or a `>` ANYWHERE in the string.

My original thought was just this: `/^[^<>].*@.*\..*[a-z]$/i` , but this only fails if the < or the > are at the beginning or the end of the string. Is there a simple command I'm missing so that it'll fail if either of those characters are anywhere in the string?

Comment: Why not just do `!str.includes('<') && !str.includes('>')` instead of using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use regex?  That seems like overkill, and there is nothing simple about regex.

Why not just use the `includes()` function instead?

```
!str.includes(">") && !str.includes("<")
```

Comment: Oh man. Yeah, I completely forgot about the includes function. I ended up using this and it works like a charm. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Keep in mind that `String.prototype.includes()` is not supported by Internet Explorer

Comment: Good point.  If IE is a concern, a polyfill or the `indexOf()` function can be used.

Comment: @amacdonald, @amy is worth noting that if `indexOf()` will be used instead of `includes()`, they can't be checked always in the same way. If one of the invalid characters appears at the beginning of the string (e.g. `<somstring`), `includes()` would result in `true` where `indexOf()` could result in `false`, because 0 is falsey.

Comment: But this is a bit wordier than simply writing `!/[<>]/.test(str)`.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy `indexOf` always returns an integer, -1 if not found.

Comment: @torazaburo yes. And if the character is found at the first position, it will return `0`. In that case, for `'>somestring'`, where `if(str.includes(">"))` would return `true`, `if(str.indexOf(">"))` would return `false`. That's why i said that they can't be checked always in the same way.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I don't know what you mean by `if (str.indexOf(">"))` would return `false`. `if` statements don't return anything; they evaluate the specified condition. If you mean that using the result of `indexOf` directly as the condition in an `if` statement would result in a falsy condition if the match occurs at the first position, of course that's true. That's why no-one would do that, and would instead check for the result being equal to -1. Amy's comment that you could also use `indexOf` did no mean that it could be used as a direct replacement.

Comment: Correct, I did not mean to imply it could be directly substituted.

Comment: @torazaburo well, read what i wrote, and you will see that i was talking about this case of `indexOf` along with `if`. You can't assume that *"That's why no-one would do that"* because we have a lot of new developers here who couldn't know about how `indexOf` works, and could think that `includes` and `indexOf` would do the same, based on the answer, along with the third comment wrote by Amy, where it is suggested that `indexOf` could be used instead of `includes`.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy In that case, add a comment clarifying that if using `indexOf` you need to write `if (str.indexOf("<") === -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The RegExp that you need is just simple as `/<|>/`. Test `'not<ok>string'.match(/<|>/);` and `'okstring'.match(/<|>/)`

```js
var okString = 'okstring';
var notOkString = 'not<ok>string';

if(okString.match(/<|>/)){
    console.log('this won\'t log'); 
}

if(notOkString.match(/<|>/)){
    console.log('this will log'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated character class instead of `.*` in your regex:

```
/^[^<>]*@[^<>]*\.[^<>]*[a-z]$/i
```

`[^<>]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `<` or `>`

Or else just to test presence of `<` or `>` use:

```
var ret = /[<>]/.test(string); // true means presence of < or >
```

Comment: Wouldn't a negative lookahead be better?

Comment: Performance-wise negated character class will always beat lookaheads but yes we can also use: `/^(?!.*[<>]).*@.*\..*[a-z]$/i`